# How to write to executable's input in C?

Tags: c

How to run an executable from within a C program so that to write data (e.g. some integer) to this executable's input?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].

Comment: Too many smarties perhaps - What is the question

Comment: Are you looking to fork, exec, and perform stdin redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method is to use `popen()`. This opens a pipe to an executable allowing you to write data to it via the executable's stdin. See the [man page for popen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) for full details.

Comment: Is it the right idea? `FILE * file = popen("./myprog", "w"); fwrite(&intvar,sizeof(int),1, file);`

Comment: Well for stdin you'd probably want to write the integer as a text value, so it would be `fprintf(file, "%d", intvar);` and then you could read it in the executable using `scanf` or whatever.